# focus event is firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I wanted a excel like functionality where All negative values are putted inside parentheses & when I focus on that field it will display Actual Negative Value like (500) => -500 & (2,500) => -2,500 on focus event & on blur I've to change values as it was previous like -2,500 onBlur converted to (2,500)!

I've written a code for that, Here is the codesandbox!

https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-tdd-10ene0?file=/src/App.js

but onfocus event is running multiple times!!

Help me to find the Actual bug, Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!!!

Comment: Please note: A proper [mre] that illustrates your issue, belongs directly into your question. Do not just dump the whole thing onto external platforms.

Comment: Actually you're mixing Vanilla JS with React which could lead to potential problems later on. Try to build JSX based on `input` and use onFocus/onBlur handlers to format inside values. You also have to learn how to build controlled form elements in React in order to handle users' submitted values.

Comment: thanks for the information bro, but i've some custom requirement, where I've to import the HTML template as a string & render it using dangerouslysetinnerhtml, That's why I'm using this type of mixing behavior!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using `addEventListener` which "adds" an event. Therefore, in some scenarios, there is a common mistake people do where they call their code several times, and therefore apply the same event several times.

Basically, your event is added several times.

A simple way to fix this is to set the event via the property of the HTMLElement like this:

```js
input.onfocus = () => {
  input.value = input.value.replace("(", "").replace(")", "") * -1;
  input.select();

  console.log("focus value", input.value);
};

input.onblur = () => {
  input.value = "(" + input.value * -1 + ")";
  console.log("blur", input.value);
};
```